# I need help trying to replicate the flow I follow when using Github on Bitbucket

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, pull-request, git-flow

I have both accounts and projects on both services. I try to replicate my Github flow on bitbucket projects but so far it has not been possible. The git management is the same, but the issues or differences appear when using the GUI on the web to accept PRs.

My Github flow is as follows:

1. I clone the project
2. I usually have `master` and `develop` branches.
3. I create a `feature/` branch with code of a new feature
4. I create a pull request from that `feature/` branch to develop
5. The pull request is reviewed by a peer or client.
6. If the PR is ok, I make sure the `feature/` branch is rebased with develop and proceed to merge with `develop` locally and then push develop to the remote.
7. `GITHUB` knows that the PR with the `feature/` branch has been merged with develop and marks the PR as merged.
8. I go to the PR and delete the branch.

> Even though I deleted the branch, I can see the code changes from the closed PR (GUI). And I could in theory `restore` that branch in the future in case I need it. But the branch won't be there as an active branch when I do `git branch -r`

I try to do that in bitbucket and it is just a mess.

After doing number 6. Bitbucket does not update the PR to merged. There is no option to close a PR. There is only an option to `approve`, `decline`, or `merge`. But I do not want to merge using the GUI is to cumbersome. I would rather merge manually.

So now what we are doing is `declining` PRs. And adding a message that says that the PR was merged manually. But this feels bad to me.

[image: Declined PR image]

The other thing is that I have a lot of branches, and if I delete a branch of a PR that has been declined then the PR that is associated with that branch will appear as empty with no commits! So history is lost.

[image: Image showing that a declined PR has no changes]

Is bitbucket proposed flow different? Should I change something here?

I am trying to get more information about what is the common flow people follow when using bitbucket rather than Github.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't use BitBucket so I can't directly answer your question, but IMHO this step in your workflow is abnormal: "But I do not want to merge using the GUI is to cumbersome. I would rather merge manually." Most PR tools are designed to have the tool do the merge. Note of all the major tools Bitbucket is arguably the most versatile with respect to the [different PR merge strategy options](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/pull-request-merge-strategies-844499235.html). Take a look at "rebase, fast-forward" and "rebase, merge" strategies which do the rebase automatically for you.

Comment: Thanks for your response. 
I will read more about it, and perhaps you might be right. What I am trying to do is different from the consensus.